# Unregister or override a custom ajaxTransport in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've set up an ajaxTransport for a little mocking framework I've worked on, based in part on [this post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mock-ajax-jquery-1-5#14737000001981480) I found (thanks dude who wrote that post).

```
$.ajaxTransport('mock', function);
```

I have a set up and teardown for testing, and I need a way to be able to teardown this ajaxTransport.  Once I've registered it, how can I unregister it?  If this can't be done, how can I override it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging through the jQuery source, it looks like if you register your transport with a + in front of the dataType, ie:

```
$.ajaxTransport('+mock', function);
```

The latest function registered will always be the one that matches to that transport dataType. I think might help you override it?

Comment: Thanks!  It's a shame this isn't in the documentation anywhere.